# JpaRepository for Java Spring : No property findbyUser found for type User

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a User class entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@json-id")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "USERS_SEQ", sequenceName = "S_USER_ACCOUNT")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USERS_SEQ")
  @Column(name = "USER_ID", precision = 22, scale = 0)
  private Long userId;

  @Column(name = "ID_TYPE")
  private String idType;

  @Column(name = "COUNTRY_CODE", length = 3, nullable = false)
  @NotBlank
  private String countryCode;
  }
}
```

and class UserRepository extend from JpaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  Page<User> findbyUser(User users, Pageable pageable);


}
```

when build and complie source, i have a error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findbyUser found for type User!
```

I want to search User with any field in entity. Could you please give your thoughts?

Comment: `findByUser` implies that there should be a `user` field in the `User` entity, hence the error. Take a look at [query by example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) which is what you seem to be after.

Comment: This is Spring Data JPA API. It is NOT JPA API. FWIW

Comment: @manish: tks for guide link, it helps me so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. I just researched the solution for this answer. It works well.

```
Example<User> example = Example.of(user); 
Page<User> pageResult = usersRepository.findAll(example, pageable);
```

Comment: What's the example class? Can you give a link to the documentation? Be more elaborate please. If the answer works for you please mark as accepted.

Comment: @BlazejChecinski: you can refer this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example at example 72&73

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Query` annotation to search by any field, e.g.:

```
    @Query("SELECT user FROM User user WHERE (:userId IS NULL OR user.userId = :userId) " +
            "AND (:idType IS NULL OR user.idType = :idType) " +
            "AND (:countryCode IS NULL OR user.countryCode = :countryCode) ")
    Page<User> search(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("idType") String idType,
                                        @Param("countryCode") String countryCode, Pageable pageable);
```

Search by countryCode:

```
    userRepository.search(null, null, "US", new PageRequest(page, pageSize));
```

Search by type and countryCode:

```
    userRepository.search(null, "someType", "US", new PageRequest(page, pageSize));
```

Search by id:

```
    userRepository.search(1L, null, null, new PageRequest(page, pageSize));
```

Comment: using JPA and Spring AND SQL-like statements pretty much is an antipattern, you're destroying all of your benefits from doing so

Comment: not quite understand what benefits were destroyed by using this JPQL syntax.

Comment: literally all of the benefits from using a proper ORM like JPA - well ... most of them, actually. If you write SQL (or JPQL) you could also ditch JPA entirely and simply work with JDBC

Comment: JPA is not ORM, but standard specification for ORM e.g: Hibernate and I can see nothing wrong to use JPQL syntax (which is a part of the JPA) in this case.

Comment: that statement doesnt make any sense whatsoever. JPA is a [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). ORM is a term describing software frameworks **like** JPA - which is actually a **specification / standard** for Java implementations of ORM. Next time : do a bit of google searching before you start assuming things, please

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make 3 different methods:

`Page<User> findAllByUserId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);`

`Page<User> findAllByIdType(String idType, Pageable pageable);`

`Page<User> findAllByCountryCode(String countryCode, Pageable pageable);`

In `@Service`, get the content from all pages and merge them into one `Page<User>`

Note that those methods could return a list of users and your `@Controller` can return a `Page<User>`.(this could make the the build up for the `@Controller` response lighter and easier)